# SlidesJS Autoplay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoplay, slidesjs

I am trying to make autoplay work on a simple SlidesJS carousel:
http://www.cycle22x.com/

I checked out some other threads that answer similar problems but the solutions provided aren't working? Here is the script that is included in the file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() 
{
    $('#slides').slidesjs(
    {
        play: 1000,
        pause: 10,
        hoverPause: true,
        width: 960,
        height: 540,
        navigation: 
        {
            effect: "fade"
        },
        pagination: 
        {
            effect: "fade"
        },
        effect: 
        {
            fade: 
            {
                speed: 400
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `auto: true` to make it autoplay, like:

```
...
$('#slides').slidesjs({
   width: 940,
   height: 528,
   play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4000,
      swap: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      restartDelay: 2500
   }
});
```

See here:: [Example Autoplay](http://slidesjs.com/examples/playing/)